# Does linux gcc/clang generate debug code to check stack balance?

Tags: linux, debugging, gcc, stack

On windows, VC compiler will generate debug version code with _chkesp implicit functions at the end of function calls, and allocate some 0xCCCCCCCC buffer on the stack to check and prevent stack corruption.

Does gcc/clang has same ability to provide extra stack check/prevention by some command line options? Either additional stack space or stack checkings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GCC supports the `-fstack-protector` and `-fstack-protector-all` [options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.3.2/gcc/Optimize-Options.html). Note that both are geared toward security hardening rather than debugging.  Instead, consider using 
the GCC/CLANG [address sanitizer](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AddressSanitizer.html) (ASAN) options ([minimal example](https://github.com/dspinellis/effective-debugging/tree/master/dlib/asan)) or [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) ([minimal example](https://github.com/dspinellis/effective-debugging/tree/master/valgrind)).